# Error creating Node.js Express App using Intellij Idea

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, intellij

I am new with Ubuntu. I am trying to create a sample node js with express project using intellij on ubuntu.

I have installed node, nodejs, npm, express and when I create a new project using intellij with the project type as node. I get the following error message before the project files are created.

```
Error creating Node.js Express App. Failed command:
/usr/bin/npm install
Exit code: 56
Standard error:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/morgan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-favicon
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-parser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-favicon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/morgan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/etag
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/on-finished
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/on-headers
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/basic-auth
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/depd
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/etag
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/on-finished
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/2.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-errors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/0.4.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/4.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/basic-auth
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.7.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-errors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/on-headers
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/2.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/depd
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/0.4.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/4.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/0.1.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-addr
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.13.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vary
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten/1.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/content-disposition/0.5.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/0.4.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vary
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.13.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten/1.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-disposition/0.5.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/0.1.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-addr
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/0.4.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ee-first/1.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/statuses
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/media-typer/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ee-first/1.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/unpipe/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/statuses
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/media-typer/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/unpipe/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/unpipe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forwarded
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.5.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/unpipe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forwarded
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/destroy/1.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.3.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.3.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/destroy/1.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/0.5.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jstransformer/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/1.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/2.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/constantinople
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/void-elements
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/with
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/constantinople
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/void-elements
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/1.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/with
npm ERR! Error: EROFS, symlink '../mime/cli.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /media/sf_SVN_HOME_2/YASSER/temp/untitled
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno 56
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jstransformer/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/2.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn-globals
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-promise
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promise
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn-globals
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-promise
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/promise
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/css
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/css-parse/1.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/css-stringify/1.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/css-parse/1.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/css-stringify/1.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asap
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/media/sf_SVN_HOME_2/YASSER/temp/untitled/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  jade@1.11.0 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/media/sf_SVN_HOME_2/YASSER/temp/untitled/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/media/sf_SVN_HOME_2/YASSER/temp/untitled/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /media/sf_SVN_HOME_2/YASSER/temp/untitled/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

but all relevant files and folder structure can be seen.

[image]

Should I be worrying about this ? Or should I ignore this, I get this on every project create.

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

I tried what [michaelms](https://askubuntu.com/users/2079/michaelms) suggested - http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html. I think for some reason express framework is not installed properly. Here is a console dump of what I just tried.

```
yasser@yasser-VirtualBox:~$ sudo npm install express-generator -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/2.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.5.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sorted-object/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sorted-object/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/2.7.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.5.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-readlink
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-readlink
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
/usr/local/bin/express -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.13.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── sorted-object@1.0.0
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
└── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
yasser@yasser-VirtualBox:~$ express -h
yasser@yasser-VirtualBox:~$ express myapp
yasser@yasser-VirtualBox:~$
```

Comment: The folder structure that you interact with might look fine, but it looks like installing dependencies inside `node_modules` failed in a couple cases. I've never used intellij; what happens if you [create an app using the express generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html)?

Comment: @michaelms I tried that just now, its not working too. Have updated my question with more findings.